# $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ describe the motions of $R$ and $S$ traveling in the same direction along the same curve. $r(0)=s(0)$ Which is true?

Tags: calculus

Let $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ be two differentiable vector functions describing the motions of two particles $R$ and $S$ traveling in the same direction along the same curve. Also given, $r(0)=s(0)$

Which of the options are correct? (Allowed to have more than $1$)

> Shaded are my answers. For this question, I shall think $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ as balls traveling through $x$-axis at different speed of $(x,0)$ and $(x^2,0)$

(I) If $r(t)$ is smooth, then $s(t)$ is smooth.

> True. Speed not equals to $0$ for $R.$  Since $r'(t)\neq \langle 0,0,0 \rangle$ for any t, $s'(t)$ similarly.

(II) If the speed of $R$ at any point on the curve is $10$ times that of $S$, then $r(t)=s(10t)$ for all t.

> False.
>
> $r'(t)=10s'(t)$.
>
> Integrate both sides w.r.t t, we have $r(t)+c_1=s(10t)+c_2$.
>
> Since $c_1,c_2$ can be any number, $r(t)\neq s(10t)$.

(III) Suppose $r(1)=s(2)$ and suppose $r'(1)$ and $s'(2)$ are non-zero vectors. Then $r'(1)/|r'(1)|=s'(2)/|s'(2)|$

> False. This option asks if the unit tangent vectors or r and s are the same. I am not sure how to explain.

My answers says False True False, which is an opposite of my thoughts.. Why? I am so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for sharing your thoughts in an organized way.

> For this question, I shall think $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ as balls traveling through x-axis at different speed of $(x,0)$ and $(x^2,0)$

It is often helpful to keep an illustrative example in mind. But be careful not to make make conclusion about general functions $r$ and $s$ on the basis of any particular example. Conclusions should be rooted in general statements (theorems) about differentiable functions, and the assumptions stated in this problem.

(I) Although $r$ and $s$ travel along the same curve, they do not necessarily do it at the same speed. In fact, no relation between the velocity vectors $r'$ and $s'$ is given to us. It is conceivable that $s$ could suddenly stop or speed up, making it non-smooth. For example: $s(t)=(t,0)$ when $t<1$ and $s(t)=(2t-1,0)$ when $t\ge 1$. This describes a particle traveling along a line, which initially moves with speed $1$ but then suddenly increases the speed. This is not a smooth function. (Why?)

(II) You forgot the assumption $r(0)=s(0)$. The constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ must be such that this assumption is satisfied. If you think this through, you will find that $c_1=c_2$.

(III) Recall that both $r$ and $s$ move along a smooth curve. Consider the point given by $r(1) $ (same as $s(2)$): there is a tangent line at that point. The velocity vectors of both $r$ and $s$ lie on that line. They also point in the same direction (why? reread the problem). Their magnitudes may be different, but the magnitude is removed by division: only direction remains.

Comment: Excellent thanks for your time.